# VbTab alignment issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have a listbox in VBA Excel application, where it reads three different columns and lists their contents on a single line. But the width of each item in a column varies. Thus, when I display it in the list box using "vbtab" it is not aligning the next item properly. For example, when the first item has 4 characters, it pulls the second closer, whereas if the first item has 8 characters, it pushes the second item a little too far. Any idea how to fix this?

Below is the code I am using.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:a50")
MySearch = Array("Tba")
For i = LBound(MySearch) To UBound(MySearch)
Set rng = .Find(what:=MySearch(i), _
After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False)

firstaddress = rng.Address


Do
j = 1
drovedate = rng.Offset(0, j)
j= j + 1
drivenby = rng.Offset(0, j)
j = j + 6
reason = rng.Offset(0, j)
x = x + 1
Dim LineOfText As String

CPHlsttheeba.AddItem (x & "   " & drovedate & vbTab() & vbTab & drivenby & vbTab & vbTab & reason)


Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
Loop While Not rng Is Nothing And rng.Address <> firstaddress
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe it is set to 5 by default, but I haven't set anything manually.

Comment: No I mean width of the text content that goes in each column

Comment: If you want to do it this way (ie. not using separate columns) then set the listbox text to a non-proportional font (eg. courier) and pad your individual pieces of text with spaces so everything's the same width.

Comment: Sorry, the max width would be 8

Comment: In that case it becomes even more easier :) You can set the columnwidth to 8. Let me post an example

Comment: Tim, what do you mean by pad individual pieces of text with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

If your text width is known then you can use the `.ColumnWidths` of the `ListBox1` to predefine the column width. This will ensure that the data is aligned properly. If the text width is not known then you can set the `.ColumnWidths` to something which you feel will accommodate all words. In the below example I have set it to `50`

The other trick is not to add the data in a loop to the `ListBox1` but to store it in an array and then set the `.List` property of the `ListBox1` to that array. This will ensure that the execution of the code is faster.

Here is an example. I am manually filling the array here. You can fill the array in your `Do While Loop`

**CODE**:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim Myarray(1 To 2, 1 To 4) As String

    Myarray(1, 1) = "Sid"
    Myarray(1, 2) = "Apple"
    Myarray(1, 3) = "Banana"
    Myarray(1, 4) = "Mumbai"
    Myarray(2, 1) = "New Delhi"
    Myarray(2, 2) = "New York"
    Myarray(2, 3) = "Japan"
    Myarray(2, 4) = "asdfghjkl"

    With Me.ListBox1
        .Clear
        .ColumnHeads = False
        .ColumnCount = 4

        .List = Myarray

        '~~> Change 50 to 8 in your application
        .ColumnWidths = "50;50;50;50"
        .TopIndex = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

**SCREENSHOT**:

[image]

**FOLLOWUP**

> Sorry, i am not sure how to fit my codings to work with an array and
>   to list them.. Would you be able to help me out a bit.. – user1697952
>   1 hour ago

Try this (*Untested*)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim n As Long

    With CPHlsttheeba
        .ColumnHeads = False
        .ColumnCount = 4
        .ColumnWidths = "8;8;8;8"
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:a50")
        MySearch = Array("Tba")
        For i = LBound(MySearch) To UBound(MySearch)
            Set rng = .Find(what:=MySearch(i), _
            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False)

            firstaddress = rng.Address

            Do
                j = 1
                drovedate = rng.Offset(0, j)
                j = j + 1
                drivenby = rng.Offset(0, j)
                j = j + 6
                reason = rng.Offset(0, j)
                x = x + 1
                Dim LineOfText As String

                CPHlsttheeba.AddItem "Test" & n, n
                CPHlsttheeba .List(n, 0) = drovedate
                CPHlsttheeba .List(n, 1) = drivenby
                CPHlsttheeba .List(n, 2) = reason

                n = n + 1

                Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
            Loop While Not rng Is Nothing And _
            rng.Address <> firstaddress
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, i am not sure how to fit my codings to work with an array and to list them.. Would you be able to help me out a bit..

Comment: Ok do this. In design mode set the `ColumnWidths` to 8 and `ColumnCount = 4`. Then add the item as you are currently adding. See if it works...

Comment: No, though the columnWidths changed to 8 pt, still not aligning

Comment: I have updated the above post. See Followup. I have not tested it so let me know if you get any errors.

Comment: sorry, i was away and i am inputting your coding now. Will get back to you shortly.

Comment: May i know what do you mean by listbox1.list. The only list box that i have is CPHlsttheeba.

Comment: Yes sorry. Replace `ListBox1` by `CPHlsttheeba`. I have updated the code above.

Comment: THanks, I did the change and tried and it is only displying drovedate. I checked it using F8, and it drivenby and reason are getting values, but not displaying them.

Comment: where do i upload and how. I have never uploaded a file on this website.

Comment: you can add it to wikisend.com and then share the link here.

Answer (score 2):

Siddharth's approach is better I think, but since you asked...

Instead of this:

```
CPHlsttheeba.AddItem  x & "   " & drovedate & vbTab() & vbTab & _
                      drivenby & vbTab & vbTab & reason
```

you can do this:

```
CPHlsttheeba.AddItem RPad(x & "   " & drovedate, 20) & _
                     RPad(drivenby, 20) & reason




'pad a string "s" on the right with spaces to total length "num"
Function RPad(s, num)
    RPad = Left(s & String(num," "), num)
End Function
```

You may need to adjust the amount of padding depending on how long your strings are.
If you format your listbox using a fixed-with font then your "columns" should line up.

Comment: Tim, your method is much better than mine. My list box is set to font size 12 but it is still not dead aligned. Thank you.,

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation creating a table in a MsgBox. I started with:

Item 1, tab, Item 2, tab, item 3.

But sometimes Item 1 or Item 2 was too long, requiring 2 tabs to keep things lined up. Some simple testing in the Immediate Window showed me that the default vbTab is 8 characters wide. So here is what I did inside a loop, then the MsgBox displayed this after the loop:

```
strMsg = strMsg & ary(1, m) & vbTab & IIf(Len(ary(1, m)) < 8, vbTab, "") & IIf(Len(ary(1, m)) < 16, vbTab, "") & ary(2, m) & vbTab & IIf(Len(ary(2, m)) < 8, vbTab, "") & ary(3, m) & vbCr
```

This essentially puts 2 or 3 tabs between results if the length of the previous result is small.